# Transparent Conductive Paint

Tags: electrical, conductive

Does anyone know of a transparent conductive paint? I am creating some home made electroluminescent panels and I need something what would work with water based polyurethane. Ive had some luck with PEDOT:PSS but I don't like the blue tint it gives and it has a tendency to pool over the polyurethane I am using for the layers under the PEDOT:PSS.

Comment: [ITO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium_tin_oxide)? But I expect it has similar limitations to what you're already using.

Comment: Indium, Yag doped polymer film ?  PPy-DBS with PV-dF?

Comment: How would I use ITO? Could I just mix it with polyurethane?